# tiny_mce.js does not load in Prestashop

Tags: tinymce, prestashop

I have a prestashop site.
The file `http://yogly.co.il/js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js` is not loading and causes a bug: `Uncaught ReferenceError: tinyMCE is not defined`
When I debug it with Chrome I see the file is empty.
Even direct access to the file shows as if the file is empty. 
If I FTP to the file I see it is 200KB.

Answer (score 0):

You can load TinyMCE from CacheFly CDN

```
<html>
<head><!-- CDN hosted by Cachefly -->
    <script src="//tinymce.cachefly.net/4.0/tinymce.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        tinymce.init({selector:'textarea'});
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <textarea>Your content here.</textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the HTML as provided at TinyMCE homepage. It does the explanation.

Comment: This doesn't help either... I am using Prestashop and the html is generated actively. I think the location of the tiny_mce.js is hard coded somewhere but I am not sure were. Tried to download the version from cachefly and use it instead, overwriting the previous version in prestashop but it didn't help

Answer (score 0):

too late answer i guess but if after replacing the `tiny_mce.js` and `tiny_mcs.min.js` still the error is same then add following code at given location :

```
prestashop/js/admin/tinymce_inc.js
```

replace this :

```
tinyMCE.init(config);
```

with this :

```
if (typeof tinyMCE !== 'undefined' && typeof tinyMCE != undefined && tinyMCE != "" && tinyMCE != null) {
        tinyMCE.init(config);
}
```

then go to AdvanceParameters/Performance in Back Office and clear cache and reload product page.

hope this fix your issue as it fix mine.

> Note:- this code is allowed to skip tiny_MCE error so all the other js works, but tiny mce editor is not appear whenever this error is skipped. you can get only simple textarea on product descriptions like : meta_description and description in INFO of product tab.

Regard,
Hardik